# SwiftyJSON error

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a class with init a build method that i want to use to create instances of class.

Code is the following

```
class Article {

let id:Int
let title:String
let subtitle:String
let editor1:String
let mainImage:NSData

init(id:Int, title:String, subtitle:String, editor1:String, mainImage:NSData) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.editor1 = editor1
    self.mainImage = mainImage
}

class func build(json:JSON) -> Article {
        id = Int(json["id"].string),
        title = json["title"].string,
        subtitle = json["subtitle"].string,
        editor1 = json["editor1"].string,
        mainImage = json["images"]["main"].rawData() {
            return Article(
                id: id,
                title: title,
                subtitle: subtitle,
                editor1: editor1,
                mainImage: mainImage)
    }
}

}
```

But i have errors

[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftyJSON's `.rawData()` is an Optional getter.

So I guess what you wanted to do is use `if let`:

```
class func build(json:JSON) -> Article? {
    id = Int(json["id"].string)
    title = json["title"].string
    subtitle = json["subtitle"].string
    editor1 = json["editor1"].string
    if let mainImage = json["images"]["main"].rawData() {
        return Article(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            subtitle: subtitle,
            editor1: editor1,
            mainImage: mainImage)
    } else {
        // ...
        return nil
    }
}
```

*Also it looks like that you copied/pasted the parameters from your Article initializer to declare them earlier in the function but you forgot to get rid of the commas at the end of the lines.*

**Update**

Your problem is that your class properties are immutable (declared with `let`) but inside this function you are trying to change their values:

```
id = Int(json["id"].string)
```

This is interpreted as

```
self.id = Int(json["id"].string)
```

And you can't change the value of `self.id` because it is immutable.

Solutions:

1- Make the properties mutable by using `var` instead of `let`. Example:

```
var id:Int
var title:String
var subtitle:String
var editor1:String
var mainImage:NSData
```

or

2- Do not replace the properties in the function since you're going to init with your new object anyway. Example:

```
class func build(json:JSON) -> Article? {
    if let img = json["images"]["main"].rawData() {
        return Article(
            id: Int(json["id"].string),
            title: json["title"].string,
            subtitle: json["subtitle"].string,
            editor1: json["editor1"].string,
            mainImage: img)
    } else {
        // ...
        return nil
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

If the compiler complains about "not marked with try", do the "if let" with "try?":

```
if let img = try? json["images"]["main"].rawData() {
```

Explanation: SwiftyJSON may have changed this method without updating the documentation yet (or I didn't find it). It previously returned an Optional and now seems to "throw" instead. Using "try?" lets you make it an Optional again.

Comment: something is wrong, cannot get what https://s.mail.ru/QYaHvmFrpj55/img-2015-10-13-18-25-46.png

Comment: Thanks a lot! Totally missed let thing

Comment: second way almost worked, but now it complains about NSData https://s.mail.ru/3wg2LLRuaAeh/img-2015-10-13-18-45-04.png

Answer (score 1):

Couple things look off.

1. You should be returning `Article?` since there is a chance you're going to be returning nil.
2. You've got a number of extraneous commas after things like `id = Int(json["id...`. Get rid of them.
3. That closure seems unnecessary. Simply check for the valid JSON first, if its bad return nil, otherwise build it up and return the article.

Answer (score 0):

You have ,s where they shouldn't be. Try using this:

```
class func build(json:JSON) -> Article {
    id = Int(json["id"].string)
    title = json["title"].string
    subtitle = json["subtitle"].string
    editor1 = json["editor1"].string
    mainImage = json["images"]["main"].rawData() {
        return Article(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            subtitle: subtitle,
            editor1: editor1,
            mainImage: mainImage)
    }
}
```